# Keras' predict() method with seq2seq encoder-decoder Transformer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transformer-model

I am fitting a transformer encoder-decoder seq2seq model in keras. It is fairly standard and I fit it using functional API. When I instantiate the model, I provide the input to it in the following format:

```
keras.Model(
    [input_seq, target_seq[:, :-1]],
    target_seq[:, 1:],
)
```

`target_seq[:, :-1]` is the input to transformer decoder, whereas `target_seq[:, 1:]` is the same sequence but offset by 1 step forward. This all is done in more or less the same way as in Chollet's "Deep Learning with Python". I used `keras_nlp.layers.TransformerEncoder` and `keras_nlp.layers.TransformerDecoder` layers.

The question I have is related to `.predict()` method. I have fitted the model, it appears to work well and I now want to make predictions on new data. I don't have target sequence anymore. What do I have to replace `target_seq[:, :-1]` with in order to run `fitted_model.predict([input_seq, ?])`?

There is a function to do that shown in the same book "Deep learning with Python". In this case we have machine translation example, from English to Spanish. But this function takes eternity to process even moderate amount of data, as it calls model on each token in each sequence iteratively. There probably is a faster way of achieving the same thing.

```
import numpy as np
spa_vocab = target_vectorization.get_vocabulary()
spa_index_lookup = dict(zip(range(len(spa_vocab)), spa_vocab))
max_decoded_sentence_length = 20
  def decode_sequence(input_sentence):
    tokenized_input_sentence = source_vectorization([input_sentence])
    decoded_sentence = "[start]"
    for i in range(max_decoded_sentence_length):
      tokenized_target_sentence = target_vectorization(
                                [decoded_sentence])[:, :-1]
      predictions = transformer(
                  [tokenized_input_sentence, tokenized_target_sentence])
      sampled_token_index = np.argmax(predictions[0, i, :])
      sampled_token = spa_index_lookup[sampled_token_index]
      decoded_sentence += " " + sampled_token
      if sampled_token == "[end]":
          break
    return decoded_sentence
```